# Laravel - перенести update из SQL в querybuilder

Tags: php, laravel, join, querybuilder

Имею следующий SQL запрос:

```
update LOW_PRIORITY zoho_contacts z
inner join
(select contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date
from zoho_invoices
where deleted_at is null and due_date is not null and summa_oplaty > 0
group by contactid ) co using (contactid)
set z.data_pervoy_pokupki = co.mini_date
where z.contactid = co.contactid AND z.data_pervoy_pokupki IS null
```

пытаюсь переписать его в синтаксисе QB:

```
DB::table('zoho_contacts z')
->innerJoin(DB::table('zoho_invoices')
->select(DB::raw('contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date'))
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->whereNotNull('due_date')
->where('summa_oplaty', '>', 0)
->groupBy('contactid') . ' as co', 'z.contactid', 'co.contactid' )
->update(['z.data_pervoy_pokupki' => 'co.mini_date'])
->where('z.contactid', 'co.contactid')
->whereNull('z.data_pervoy_pokupki');

dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
>   которая указывает на строку
>   ->groupBy('contactid') . ' as co', 'z.contactid', 'co.contactid' )

думаю, что это относится к

> ' as co'

**Подскажите плз - куда это ' as co' правильно пристроить?**

Зачем мне это ' as co'? Это алиас таблицы, которую нужно "приджойнить"... По-другому не придумал. В обычном запросе оно работает.

Answer (score 0):

решение найдено с помощью ментора:

```
DB::table('zoho_contacts')
    ->join(DB::raw("(select contactid,  min(due_date) as mini_date from zoho_invoices
    where deleted_at is null and due_date is not null and summa_oplaty > 0
    group by contactid ) co"),"zoho_contacts.contactid","=","co.contactid")
        ->where('zoho_contacts.contactid', 'co.contactid')
        ->whereNull('zoho_contacts.data_pervoy_pokupki')
        ->update(['zoho_contacts.data_pervoy_pokupki' => 'co.mini_date']) ;
```

пришлось распрощаться с алисом 'z' для 1-й таблицы - заменить его на полное имя и большую часть запроса поместить в `DB::raw`, но это работает и это хорошо!